# Accurate method or instrument to measure density of shaving cream foam or whipped cream foam?

Tags: measurements, instrumentation, air

I am currently filling a "standard" stainless steel cup of known volume with foam and then I weigh it. Then I calculate density. This method is pretty messy and I have to be careful about how I fill the stainless steel cup so that larger air pockets aren't trapped on accident. I need to figure out a less messy and more reliable method that would allow me to read or calculate specific gravity of the foam more frequently.

I tried fabricating a tube that could be filled with foam from one end and then just scrape the excess foam on both ends, but it turned out to be messier than the original method.

Answer (score 1):

For a less messy way to determine the volume of shaving cream use a three dimension scanner and software that can determine the volume of scanned items.

1. Acquire some stainless steel, plastic or ceramic tiles.
2. Weigh a tile.
3. Place a dollop of cream on the tile.
4. Weigh the tile with the cream & subtract the mass of the tile.
5. Place the tile with cream in a 3D scanner and determine the volume.
6. With mass and volume of the dollop of cream known, calculate the
   density.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick a plastic soda bottle and make two holes on the cap.

One large enough to stick a stub of plastic straw for receiving the foam the other as a discharge.

Once you have the foam oozing out of the discharge hole, you can weigh and subtract it by the empty bottle weight.

Comment: Isn't this kinda similar to the method @agentboo used where she used a tube. If not, what's the difference.